# Chaining addEventListeners will lead to low performance over time

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've recently created a web app that is built upon the dependency between 3 major buttons. 
The app is a capital finder project. To make a summary, in this app I have a set of buttons that are responsible with the region select. After the user does select one of the regions, he'll have to press a button that renders a random country from the selected region and a set of 4 buttons that are the capital choices. The user will choose one of the options and he will get a feedback message and the color of the button will change accordingly. The app runs smooth at the beginning but after some regions get changed, it starts to render the data very slow and with lots of delays.

To create this button clicking order for the desired result I have included 3 addEventListener functions that depend on the other one. So as it can be seen in the example bellow, the buttons will log the desired value only when the previous one has been already selected. The problem is that if button 1 and 2 are selected multiple times, the 3rd button will somehow adds up the values from the previous times. This is the thing that makes my app slower and slower over use. Hope there can be a solution for this.

Steps to repro: 
1. Click on the first button several times
2. Click on the second button several times
3. Click only once on the 3rd button

```js
const buton1 = document.querySelector('#btn1')

buton1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Hello from button 1')

  const buton2 = document.querySelector('#btn2')
  buton2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Hello from button 2')

    const buton3 = document.querySelector('#btn3')
    buton3.style.background = 'white'
    buton3.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Hello from button 3')
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn1">1St Button</button>
  <button id="btn2">2nd Button</button>
  <button id="btn3">3rd</button>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Well, you add more and more event listeners to the same button and they all write to the console. I'm not sure why you want to do that.

Comment: This is just an example. The idea is that in my app every button does something specific that cannot be done if a previous button hasn't been clicked before.

Comment: Yes, but you are still adding more and more event listeners and never removing the old ones. Again, I'm not sure why you want to do that.

Comment: How would I be able to remove the old ones? This is what would help me. The app runs perfectly at the beginning, all the data is rendered as it should be. After some clicks the app will be increasingly slower because as you said, I don t remove the old ones. How can I do that for each click of each button? The behavior I would like to have is the one as in the snippet above, only if the buttons are clicked in order for the first time.

Comment: You can't remove event listeners added as anonymus functions. If for whatever reason you absolutely must use it this way you can change to named functions then remove with `.removeEventListener('click', yourFunctionName)`

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically asigning listeners isn't the best way of controlling flow, as you've found out it can cause a bit of bloat.

Here's a quick example of above with a single event listener and an attribute that you can assign to the element to determine the click order wanted.

```js
let clicked = [];
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    if(e.target.matches('.funButton')){
        let thisOrder = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-clickOrder'));
        if(clicked.length === thisOrder){
            clicked.push(e.target.id);
            console.log('hello from ' + e.target.id);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="b1" class="funButton" data-clickOrder="0">1St Button</button>
<button id="b2" class="funButton" data-clickOrder="1">2nd Button</button>
<button id="b3" class="funButton" data-clickOrder="2">3rd</button>
</body>
</html>
```